# Changing Parsec Client Streaming Resolution

Tags: cloud, parsec, moonlight

Is it possible to change the parsec streaming resolution to something other than that of client's? The native maximum resolution of my remote laptop is 1920*1080. I use an ultrawide monitor, and the sides of the my screen are clipped off due to 16:9 streaming by parsec.